# Is TDI shifted on move from SHIFT-IR to EXIT2-IR in JTAG?

Tags: jtag

I'm struggeling with analyzing a JTAG signal. You can see the signal below. The state machine starts in RUN-TEST/IDLE (green):

[image: trace]

As far as I understand the standard and the trace lines, 00100 should be shifted into IR. However, the decoder (sigrok/PulseView) already shifts TDI into IR on the move from CAPTURE-IR to SHIFT-IR. In addition it does not take into account the last bit which should get shifted into IR when TMS is asserted to move to EXIT1-IR.

While the first bit is not much of a problem (it will just fall off the chain), the last bit (MSB) is actually relevant. What am I missing? I doubt the decoder is wrong as it's widely used.

The following picture illustrates my understanding of JTAG:

[image: expected trace]

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Data is shifted if the state at the rising edge of TCK is SHIFT-IR, and the next state is entered after that.

Thus, the bit at the transition from CAPTURE-IR to SHIFT-IR is not shifted, and the bit at the transition from SHIFT-IR to EXIT1-IR is.

Thus, the protocol decoder is broken.